# Sorted Files get rows only maximum values

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have sorted text files and simple awk which getting first line (Mean Maximum Value)

Forexample

```
 Key    Column1  Column2  Column3  ..... MaxValue
Test1    500     400     200               500
Test1    499     400     200               500
Test1    499     399     200               499
Test1    498     100     100               498
Test2    600     200     150               600
Test2    600     199     150               600
Test2    599     199     100               599
```

I can use shell scrip as below to get dynamic column

```
MaxValue=`awk -F'\t' -v OFS="MaxValue" 'NR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==OFS) {print i} }'
```

And I have simple code to get first row (Mean maximum value)

```
like awk '!a[$1]++'
```

Then results like below,

```
 Key    Column1  Column2  Column3  ..... MaxValue
Test1    500     400     200               500
Test2    600     200     150               600
```

Just get highest value by Key.
but I want to check another dynamic column and if same value just print.
So results like below,

```
 Key    Column1  Column2  Column3  ..... MaxValue
Test1    500     400     200               500
Test1    499     400     200               500
Test2    600     200     150               600
Test2    600     199     150               600
```

Anyone has good idea to do using awk?
Thank you!

Comment: what is the expected output?  which columns are sorted ?

Comment: Expected Output is last text, and sorted by MaxValue.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to iterate over the file twice: once to collect the maxima, once to find the lines that match them:

```
awk '
  NR == FNR && ( !($1 in max) || max[$1] < $NF ) {max[$1] = $NF} 
  NR != FNR && $NF == max[$1]
' file file
```

---

If you want to supply the name of the column containing your max values:

```
awk -v colname="Column2" '
  NR == 1 {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == colname) maxcol = i}  
  NR == FNR && ( !($1 in max) || max[$1] < $maxcol ) {max[$1] = $maxcol} 
  NR != FNR && $maxcol == max[$1]
' file file
```

You might want to add some verification that the maxcol variable is actually set to a number.

---

and adding in @tommy's suggestion

```
awk -v colname="MaxValue" '
  NR == 1 {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == colname) maxcol = i
    print
    next
  }  
  ( !($1 in max) || max[$1] < $maxcol ) {
    max[$1] = $maxcol
    n[$1] = 0
    delete lines[$1]
  } 
  max[$1] == $maxcol {lines[$1][n[$1]++] = $0}
  END { for (key in lines) for (i=0; i<n[key]; i++) print lines[key][i] }
' file
```

This one requires GNU awk for the array of arrays.

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to iterate over the file twice; he could keep the relevant lines in an array and print at the end. However, I have voted up your answer.

Comment: True, but it's a bit more code (you have to forget the remembered lines for that key if the max value changes). It's a trade-off between performance and maintainability.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer, can I do it with Dynamic columns value? like awk -v var="MaxValue"